# parsing file with r

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to parse this unstructured file using R:

ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/ratings.list.gz

```
      0000001322  175300   8.3  The Sting (1973)
      0000001123  426445   8.3  2001: A Space Odyssey (1968)
      0000001222   94315   8.3  Ladri di biciclette (1948)
      0000001222  149759   8.3  Singin' in the Rain (1952)
      0000001322  622326   8.3  Toy Story (1995)
      0000001222  599957   8.3  Snatch (2000)
```

The file has (among other junk) lines like these above. I have tried `fread` and `read.table`, all fail at some point, and I was not able to find a solution. I need a way to parse the lines by dividing them into 4 variables. With regex I would do it like this:

```
^\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S{3,4})\s+(.*)$
```

Any tips/pointers on how should I tackle this within R?

P.S. The first match has to be `\S` and not `\d` as some will look like this `.0..002212` and the third match will rarely be `10.0` hence I specified 3-4x non-whitespace. Anything after the score (ex `8.3`) is the movie title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly look at your data; the first 27 lines are prose information, and the first dataset runs from lines 28 to 278. The `readr` package's `read_table` function is a good bit smarter than `read.table`, and can handle the missing data well:

```
df <- readr::read_table('ratings.list.gz', skip = 27, n_max = 250)

df
## # A tibble: 250 x 5
##      New Distribution   Votes  Rank                                                Title
##    <chr>        <chr>   <int> <dbl>                                                <chr>
## 1          0000000125 1686502   9.2                      The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
## 2          0000000125 1153698   9.2                                 The Godfather (1972)
## 3          0000000124  789387   9.0                        The Godfather: Part II (1974)
## 4          0000000124 1671708   8.9                               The Dark Knight (2008)
## 5          0000000133  863309   8.9                              Schindler's List (1993)
## 6          0000000133  446671   8.9                                  12 Angry Men (1957)
## 7          0000000123 1322033   8.9                                  Pulp Fiction (1994)
## 8          0000000124 1213467   8.9 The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)
## 9          0000000123  502576   8.9               Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo (1966)
## 10         0000000133 1344643   8.8                                    Fight Club (1999)
## # ... with 240 more rows
```

There is then another 10-line dataset, and then the main one, which seems to contain the rest. `read_table` isn't good at seeing the splits, but as long as you tell it where to start and if it should stop, it will do the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of manually parsing the lines, you can use `read.fwf` since the lines are well structured and each column has fixed widths except for the last one, which you can specify a large enough width to cover the last column:

```
read.fwf("all.txt", widths = c(10, -2, 6, -3, 3, -2, 1000))

#     V1     V2  V3                           V4
# 1 1322 175300 8.3             The Sting (1973)
# 2 1123 426445 8.3 2001: A Space Odyssey (1968)
# 3 1222  94315 8.3   Ladri di biciclette (1948)
# 4 1222 149759 8.3   Singin' in the Rain (1952)
# 5 1322 622326 8.3             Toy Story (1995)
# 6 1222 599957 8.3                Snatch (2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the description in the file, it seems like it may get updated on some frequent basis. You may be better off trying to handle this generically

```
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

fil <- "ratings.list"
lines <- read_lines(fil) # could use the gz file instead
```

Get the starting positions of the tables:

```
starts <- which(grepl("^New", lines))
```

Get the ending positions of the tables:

```
ends <- map_int(starts, ~which(grepl("^[[:alpha:]]", lines[(.+1):length(lines)]))[1]+.)
```

Read in each table:

```
ratings <- map(seq_along(starts), ~read_table(paste0(lines[starts[.]:(ends[.]-1)], collapse="\n"))[,-1])
```

Create and/or get/make the names of each data frame:

```
df_names <- c("top_250_movies", tolower(make.names(lines[starts[-1]-2])))
df_names <- gsub("\\.+", "_", df_names)
df_names <- gsub("_$", "", df_names)

df_names
## [1] "top_250_movies"              
## [2] "bottom_10_movies_1500_votes"
## [3] "movie_ratings_report"

names(ratings) <- df_names

glimpse(ratings[[df_names[1]]])
## Observations: 250
## Variables: 4
## $ Distribution <chr> "0000000125", "0000000125", "0000000124", "000000...
## $ Votes        <int> 1686502, 1153698, 789387, 1671708, 863309, 446671...
## $ Rank         <dbl> 9.2, 9.2, 9.0, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.8,...
## $ Title        <chr> "The Shawshank Redemption (1994)", "The Godfather...

glimpse(ratings[[df_names[2]]])
## Observations: 10
## Variables: 4
## $ Distribution <dbl> 5e+09, 5e+09, 6e+09, 6e+09, 6e+09, 6e+09, 6e+09, ...
## $ Votes        <int> 7541, 7735, 14147, 13055, 15329, 30542, 12641, 25...
## $ Rank         <dbl> 1.9, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5
## $ Title        <chr> "Zombie Nation (2004)", "Titanic - La leggenda co...

glimpse(ratings[[df_names[3]]])
## Observations: 665,729
## Variables: 4
## $ Distribution <chr> "41...1..2.", "1000000102", "2...0.01.4", "0.0..0...
## $ Votes        <int> 7, 61, 12, 13, 10, 51, 15, 15, 9, 8, 5, 20, 23, 7...
## $ Rank         <dbl> 4.1, 6.3, 6.8, 7.6, 6.9, 6.6, 5.8, 6.3, 7.6, 6.8,...
## $ Title        <chr> "\"!Next?\" (1994)", "\"#1 Single\" (2006)", "\"#...
```

This shouldn't break if they ever add a new table or add movies to the tables.