# Extract a section from raw .log file in R

Tags: r, logfile

I have a log file created by a java program. The file looks like as follows:

```
26-Sep-2016 09:15:09:292, INFO, connection [driver1-1] created
[client: driver1-1 - ClassServer] Attempting connection to the class server at XXXX:11111
26-Sep-2016 09:15:09:301, INFO, [client: driver1-1 - ClassServer] Attempting  connection to the class server at XXXX:11111
26-Sep-2016 09:15:18:486, INFO,     1554 tasks completed.
26-Sep-2016 09:15:18:488, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:18:488, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:18:488, INFO, Arrangement Model tasks:
26-Sep-2016 09:15:18:490, INFO, done with Arrangement Model.
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:529, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:529, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:529, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:529, INFO, Job Types by Area
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:529, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:530, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:530, INFO, Area               Full-time      
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:530, INFO, ---------------------------------
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, 1:  Area1                  49050         
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, 2:  Area2                  31107        
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, 3:  Area3                  220020 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, 4:  Area4                  2079 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, ----------------------------------
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, Total                      302256
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:532, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:532, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:532, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:532, INFO, Employment Types by Area
```

I want to extract the following portion from the text file.

```
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:529, INFO, Job Types by Area
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:529, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:530, INFO, 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:530, INFO, Area               Full-time      
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:530, INFO, ---------------------------------
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, 1:  Area1                  49050         
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, 2:  Area2                  31107        
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, 3:  Area3                  220020 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, 4:  Area4                  2079 
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, ----------------------------------
26-Sep-2016 09:15:19:531, INFO, Total                      302256
```

I tried to do it using grep, but I was not successful. What will be the most efficient way to extract from such a log file?

Comment: Will a section always start with a line with "Job Types by area" and always end with a line with "Total"?

Comment: @Xizam, Yes, the log file will have several sections. Each section will start with a "title" and ends with "Total". In this particular case, the title is "Jobs Types by Area"

Comment: This — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926790/parsing-file-with-r/38929262#38929262 — shows how to read lines from a file, identify start/end sections and the process the remaining bit.